# Hide or encrypt parameters in query string of html.actionlink MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In ASP.NET MVC3, I am redirecting to pages from one to another, to do that below action link is used,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Proceed", "DetailsScreen", "DetailsUC", new { id= Model.id })
```

Once I click the action link the URL is passed as below with parameters,

```
http://localhost:80/TestProject/DetailsUC/DetailsScreen?id=12
```

Everything works fine, but the problem is, if I manually change the id=13 in browser url that also works which is security violation, because id=13 is for other user.

So I want to hide those parameters or encrypt, I am wondering how to do that

Comment: You handle that in the controller by checking if the parameter is valid for the user, then take the appropriate action (redirect to an error page, return 404 error etc)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks friend.. will try that option